# Generating Functions Homework Question 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

This is a HW question

The question is to use generating functions to count the number of six digit (positive) integers whose digits sum to $42$. Ex. $978468$ is a  six digit integer whose digits sum to $42$

I am only looking for a hint on how to set this up.

Comment: someone had posted an answer/hint that seemed to be very helpful but they deleted it. Was there something wrong with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_{n,s}$ is the number of $n$-digit numbers (allowing leading $0$) with digit sum $s$, then we have the recursion
$$a_{n+1,s}=\sum_{d=0}^9 a_{n,s-d}$$
So if $f_n(z)=\sum_{s=0}^\infty a_{n,s}z^s$, you can express $f_{n+1}$ using $f_{n}$ ...

Comment: thanks for the answer Hagen would there be a difference to your answer if I told you that recursion was not covered in this assignment its part of the next assignment.

Comment: what I mean is there a way to approach this without recursion

Comment: someone else had posted an answer but they deleted it for some reason. If I follow what that person had said my function would be $f(x)=(x+x^2....x^9)(1+x+x^2+...x^9)^5$ where the first term is for the first digit and the second terms is for the remaining 5 digits. Then from here I would go about finding the coefficient of $x^{42}$. Does this seem right ?